# Error when run remote powershell get-activesyncdevice on management tool 2010 against server 2007

Tags: powershell

Our company have many site, some server is 2007 and the others is 2010, I installed exchange management tool version is 2010 in a win2008 and try to make a report of all the activesync devices.

first, I run get-activesyncdevice, it cause a exception.

```
PS C:\Users\administrator.BECK07> Get-ActiveSyncDevice -Mailbox "perf-user0611"
The Get-ActiveSyncDevice cmdlet can only retrieve device information for 14 mailboxes.
At line:1 char:1
+  <<<< Get-ActiveSyncDevice -Mailbox "perf-user0611"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], TaskNotSupportedOnVersionException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AFA99CB5
```

So, I think I can use the command get-activesyncdevicestatistic but it still pop up a exception.

```
PS C:\Users\administrator.BECK07> Get-ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics -mailbox "perf-user0611"
Get-ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics : The Get-ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics command that you are trying to run, which is version 14, requires that the target mailbox account is on a Mailbox server that is the same version. The command wasn't able to process your request because the target mailbox account is on a Mailbox server with version 8. Please use this version (Version: 8) of the Get-ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics command.
At line:1 char:31
+ Get-ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics <<<<  -mailbox "perf-user0611"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics], ServerVersionNotSupportedException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : A81A5D,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Tasks.GetMobileDeviceStatistics
```

How can i get the activesync device info of the mailbox version is 2007? thanks in advance

Here is the result when I get the mailbox version.

```
PS C:\Users\administrator.BECK07> Get-Mailbox "perf-user0611" | fl exchangeversion

ExchangeVersion : 0.1 (8.0.535.0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exchange 2010 management tools are not [backwards compatible](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638174.aspx). You need to install both management tools and pick the version according to which Exchange you are managing.

Comment: Hi vonPryz, thanks for your response. Your solution is the best one I think, thanks very much